# How $\{B(t): t \leq T\}$ is $\mathcal{F}^+-$measurable in Brownian Motion, with $T$ a stopping time

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am reading the book Brownian Motion by Yuval Peres and Peter Morters. In the book the following $\sigma$-algebra is defined for a given stopping time $T$,
$$\mathcal{F}^+(T)=\{A \in \mathcal{A}: A \cap \{T \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}^+(t) \text{ for all } t \geq 0\}$$
Where, $\mathcal{F}^+(s) = \bigcap_{t > s} \sigma (B(q): 0 \leq q \leq t)$.

It is mentioned later, without proof, that the random path $\{B(t): t \leq T\}$ is $\mathcal{F}^+(T)-$measurable for any stopping time $T$. I don't understad how to prove this using the definition, I have to show that for any set in the borel sigma algebra of the function space of continuous functions the inverse image of any $B(s), s \leq T$ lies in $\mathcal{F}^+(T)$. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you should have a $\mathcal{F}^+(t)$ inside the first display, is that correct?

Comment: I think here it is really just a matter of writing all the definitions as explicitly as possible. To get that $B_T$ is $\mathcal{F}^+_T$ measurable, you need to show that $[B_T\in I] \in \mathcal{F}^+_T$  for all interval. Now, use the definition of the latter $\sigma$-field. You will have to go one definition further now. Can you see where I am going?

Comment: @Kernel So is the following correct: I have to show that $\{B(T) \in I\} \in \mathcal{F}^+(t)$. So if $\{B(T) \in I\} = A$ then we have, if $T \leq t$ then, $A \in  \mathcal{F}^+(t)$, further $\{T \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}^+(t)$ by definition, so $A \cap \{T \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}^+(t)$. Hence, $A \in \mathcal{F}^+(T)$. Somehow I feel that I am missing something here. (I guess, I am not considering the case when $T> t$?)

Comment: @Mathaddict You may ask [one of the authors](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/360408/yuval-peres) here directly :) BTW, showing that $B(T)$ is $\mathcal{F}(T)$-measurable is easy if you approximate $T$ by simple functions from above.

Comment: @Yuval Peres It would be great if the author himself could help me with my doubt!

Comment: @d.k.o. I will try using the method that you suggested, By simple functions do you mean the discrete approximation similar used in proof of the Strong markov property?

Comment: @Mathaddict Yes. Consider $T_n:=2^{-n}\lceil 2^n T\rceil$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on my comment, we will show that given $A=[B_T \in I]$ for any interval $I$, we have $A \cap [T\le t] \in \mathcal{F}^+(t)$ for all $t$. To take this to a Borel set of $\mathbb{R}$ rather than an interval, one can use standard measurable theoretic arguments.

First, as $T$ is a stopping time, we have $[T\le t] \in \mathcal{F}(t) \subset \mathcal{F}^+(t) $, this is the definition of stopping time.

Now, as $T\le t$, we have that $(B_T)(\omega) = B^t_{\cdot}(\omega) \circ T(\omega)$ where $B^t_s(\omega):= B_{t \wedge s}(\omega)$.

As $t \mapsto B_t$ is continuous (and therefore measurable) and $\{B^t_s: s \ge 0\}$ is measurable in $\mathcal{F}^+(t)$.

Using that given two functions $f: \mathbb{R}\times \Omega \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \Omega \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, the composition $F(\omega)=f(g(\omega),\omega)$ is also measurable, we complete the answer. One can prove this last statement by taking $g$ to be a simple function first, then taking an approximation via simple function for general $g$.

Comment: This proves that $B_T$ is $\mathcal{F}^+(T)-$measurable, the same method can show that the map from $\Omega$ to $C[0,\infty)$ that takes $\omega$ to $t \mapsto B_{t \wedge T}(\omega)$ is $\mathcal{F}^+(T)-$measurable when $C[0,\infty)$ is equipped with the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets and the corresponding Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Indeed, sorry, I forgot to add the last part.